# XSLT sorting over multiple for-each

Tags: xml, excel, sorting, xslt

With Saxon 9.7 xslt v3, I am creating a spreadsheet, the content is generated in two separate `xsl:for-each` blocks.
The first block selects nodes higher up the tree, e.g. displaying information on a data model level. 
The second block includes the data level model information but goes in to more details about the variables and the model contents, creating the following output:

[image: current result]

The first four rows (1st `xsl:for-each`) are at a model level showing annotations for the data model, the preceeding rows (2nd `xsl:for-each` selecting child nodes) at a variable level with variable annotations.

I'd like to sort by data model so that the data model information plus the variable information from the second `xsl:for-each` are together.

But so far I can only `xsl:sort` within the `xsl:for-each`, and not overall for both.
I'd like to sort overall by

```
dataList/ordinal
dataList/dataListDefault/ordinal
dataList/dataListDefault/variableList/variableListDefualt/ordinal
dataList/dataListDefault/variableList/variableListDefualt/annotationList/annotationDefault/ordinal
```

What I would like to see:
[image: wanted result]

My 
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tables>
    <dataList>
        <ordinal>1</ordinal>
        <name>DATA1</name>
        <label>Data 1</label>
          <datasetList>
             <datasetListDefault> 
              <ordinal>1</ordinal>
              <name>DS1</name>  
              <annotationList>
                  <annotation> Dataset 1</annotation>
              </annotationList>
             <variableList>
               <variableListDefault>
                   <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                   <name>VAR1</name>
                   <label>Variable 1</label>
                   <annotationList>
                       <annotationDefault>
                           <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                           <annotation>This is the 1st variable</annotation>
                       </annotationDefault>
                       <annotationDefault>
                           <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                           <annotation>Variable used for analysis</annotation>
                       </annotationDefault>
                   </annotationList>
               </variableListDefault>
                 <variableListDefault>
                     <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                     <name>VAR2</name>
                     <label>Variable 2</label>
                     <annotationList>
                         <annotationDefault>
                            <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                            <annotation>This is the 2nd variable</annotation>
                         </annotationDefault>    
                     </annotationList>
                 </variableListDefault>                 
             </variableList>   
             </datasetListDefault>     
              <datasetListDefault> 
                  <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                  <name>DS2</name>
                  <annotationList>
                      <annotation> Dataset 2</annotation>
                  </annotationList>
                  <variableList>
                      <variableListDefault>
                          <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                          <name>VAR1</name>
                          <label>Variable 1</label>
                          <annotationList>
                              <annotationDefault> 
                                  <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                                  <annotation>This is the 1st variable</annotation>
                              </annotationDefault>   
                              <annotationDefault> 
                                  <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                                  <annotation>Remove when x</annotation>
                              </annotationDefault> 
                          </annotationList>
                      </variableListDefault>
                      <variableListDefault>
                          <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                          <name>VAR2</name>
                          <label>Variable 2</label>
                          <annotationList>
                              <annotationDefault>
                                <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                                <annotation>This is the 2nd variable</annotation>
                              </annotationDefault>    
                          </annotationList>
                      </variableListDefault>                 
                  </variableList>   
              </datasetListDefault>  
          </datasetList>
    </dataList>
    <dataList>
        <ordinal>2</ordinal>
        <name>DATA2</name>
        <label>Data 2</label>
        <datasetList>
            <datasetListDefault> 
                <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                <name>DS21</name>  
                <annotationList>
                    <annotation> Dataset 21</annotation>
                </annotationList>
                <variableList>
                    <variableListDefault>
                        <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                        <name>VAR1</name>
                        <label>Variable 1</label>
                        <annotationList>
                            <annotationDefault>
                              <ordinal>1</ordinal>  
                              <annotation>This is the 1st variable</annotation>
                            </annotationDefault>    
                        </annotationList>
                    </variableListDefault>
                    <variableListDefault>
                        <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                        <name>VAR2</name>
                        <label>Variable 2</label>
                        <annotationList>
                            <annotationDefault>
                               <ordinal>1</ordinal>   
                               <annotation>This is the 2nd variable</annotation>
                            </annotationDefault>    
                        </annotationList>
                    </variableListDefault>                 
                </variableList>   
            </datasetListDefault>     
            <datasetListDefault> 
                <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                <name>DS22</name>
                <annotationList>
                    <annotation> Dataset 22</annotation>
                </annotationList>
                <variableList>
                    <variableListDefault>
                        <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                        <name>VAR1</name>
                        <label>Variable 1</label>
                        <annotationList>
                            <annotationDefault>
                                <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                                 <annotation>This is the 1st variable</annotation>
                            </annotationDefault>    
                        </annotationList>
                    </variableListDefault>
                    <variableListDefault>
                        <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                        <name>VAR2</name>
                        <label>Variable 2</label>
                        <annotationList>
                            <annotationDefault>
                                <ordinal>1</ordinal>
                                <annotation>This is the 2nd variable</annotation>
                            </annotationDefault>    
                        </annotationList>
                    </variableListDefault>                 
                </variableList>   
            </datasetListDefault>  
        </datasetList>
    </dataList>      
</tables>
```

and the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <ss:Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

            <xsl:call-template name="document-properties"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="document-styles"/>

            <!-- ****************************************************************************************** -->
            <!-- CREATE THE TABS IN THE WORKBOOK -->
            <!-- ****************************************************************************************** -->         
            <xsl:call-template name="getData"/>

            <!-- ****************************************************************************************** -->

        </ss:Workbook>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="getData">       

        <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Data">
            <Names>
                <NamedRange ss:Name="_FilterDatabase" ss:RefersTo="=Data!R1C1:R1C7" ss:Hidden="1"/>
            </Names>

            <ss:Table  ss:ExpandedRowCount="7000" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" >        
                <Column ss:Width="100"/>
                <Column ss:Width="300"/>
                <Column ss:Width="100"/>
                <Column ss:Width="250"/>
                <Column ss:Width="140"/>
                <Column ss:Width="140"/>                
                <Column ss:Width="400"/>

                <Row>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="sHead">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Data Model Name </Data>  
                        <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="sHead">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Data Model Label </Data>    
                        <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/>
                    </Cell>                       
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="sHead">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Dataset Name</Data>  
                        <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/>
                    </Cell>     
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="sHead">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Varaible Label</Data>     
                        <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/>
                    </Cell>      
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="sHead">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Variable Name</Data>    
                        <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/>
                    </Cell>   
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="sHead">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Annotation</Data>    
                        <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/>
                    </Cell> 
                </Row>              

                <xsl:for-each select="//datasetListDefault">   
                    <xsl:sort select="../../ordinal"/>
                        <xsl:sort select="ordinal"/>    
                    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../../name"/>
                            </Data>   
                        </Cell>   
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../../label"/>
                            </Data>   
                        </Cell>     
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </Data>   
                        </Cell>  
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String"></Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String"></Data>
                        </Cell> 
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="annotationList/annotation"/>
                            </ss:Data>   
                        </Cell>                          
                    </Row>    
                </xsl:for-each>  

                <xsl:for-each select="//variableListDefault">  
                    <xsl:sort select="../../../../ordinal"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="../../ordinal"/>    
                    <xsl:sort select="ordinal"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="following-sibling::annotationList/annotationDefault/ordinal"/>
                         <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../../../../name"/>
                            </Data>   
                        </Cell>   
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../../../../label"/>
                            </Data>   
                        </Cell>     
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../../name"/>
                            </Data>   
                        </Cell>  
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
                            </Data>   
                        </Cell>  
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </Data>   
                        </Cell>          
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="sBody">
                            <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="annotationList/annotationDefault/annotation"/>
                            </ss:Data>   
                        </Cell>  
                    </Row>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </ss:Table>
            <xsl:call-template name="worksheet-options"/>

            <AutoFilter x:Range="R1C1:R1C7" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"/>
        </ss:Worksheet>

    </xsl:template>



    <!-- 
    *************************************GENERAL TEMPLATES**************************************************
    -->

    <!-- EXCEL WORKSHEET OPTIONS -->        
    <xsl:template name="worksheet-options">
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <PageSetup>
                <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
                <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
                <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
            </PageSetup>
            <Selected/>
            <FreezePanes/>
            <FrozenNoSplit/>
            <SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>
            <TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>
            <ActivePane>2</ActivePane>
            <Panes>
                <Pane>
                    <Number>3</Number>
                    <ActiveRow>18</ActiveRow>
                    <ActiveCol>2</ActiveCol>
                </Pane>
            </Panes>
            <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
            <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
        </WorksheetOptions>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- EXCEL DOCUMENT PROPERTIES -->  
    <xsl:template name="document-properties">
        <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <Author></Author>
            <LastAuthor></LastAuthor>
            <Created>2016-08-24T10:40:32Z</Created>
            <Company></Company>
            <Version>14.00</Version>
        </DocumentProperties>
        <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <WindowHeight>14370</WindowHeight>
            <WindowWidth>27795</WindowWidth>
            <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
            <WindowTopY>120</WindowTopY>
            <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
            <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
        </ExcelWorkbook>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- EXCEL DOCUMENT STYLES -->  
    <xsl:template name="document-styles">
        <ss:Styles>
            <ss:Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                <ss:Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                <ss:Borders/>
                <ss:Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10" ss:Color="#000000"/>
                <ss:Interior/>
                <ss:NumberFormat/>
                <ss:Protection/>
            </ss:Style>
            <ss:Style ss:ID="sHead">
                <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Top" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                <ss:Borders>
                    <ss:Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <ss:Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <ss:Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <ss:Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                </ss:Borders>
                <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#FFFFFF"/>
                <ss:Interior ss:Color="#538DD5" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
            </ss:Style>
            <ss:Style ss:ID="sBody">
                <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Top" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                <ss:Borders>
                    <ss:Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <ss:Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <ss:Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <ss:Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                </ss:Borders>
                <ss:Interior ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
            </ss:Style>
        </ss:Styles>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**QUESTION**: Is there a solution for sorting the resulting data from the `xsl:for-each` blocks overall */or/* outside of the for-each */or/* post initial processing?

Further more sorting the siblings for `//variableListDefault/annotationList/annotationDefault/ordinal` I've tried to pass this through the sort
with `anaylze-string` and now `<xsl:sort select="following-sibling::annotationList/annotationDefault/ordinal"/>`, without success. Which sort option would handle these siblings nodes individually and sort?

Comment: I suggest you (a) reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem and (b) post the expected result **as code** - see; [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be nesting your `xsl:for-each` statements here.

Instead of doing this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//datasetListDefault">   
    <xsl:sort select="../../ordinal"/>  
    <xsl:sort select="ordinal"/>    
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
            <!-- snip -->           
    </Row>    
</xsl:for-each>  

<xsl:for-each select="//variableListDefault">  
    <xsl:sort select="../../../../ordinal"/>
    <xsl:sort select="../../ordinal"/>    
    <xsl:sort select="ordinal"/>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
            <!-- snip -->           
    </Row>    
</xsl:for-each>
```

Do this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="//datasetListDefault">   
    <xsl:sort select="../../ordinal"/>  
    <xsl:sort select="ordinal"/>    
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
        <!-- snip -->           
    </Row>    

    <xsl:for-each select=".//variableListDefault">  
        <xsl:sort select="../../../../ordinal"/>
        <xsl:sort select="../../ordinal"/>    
        <xsl:sort select="ordinal"/>
        <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
            <!-- snip -->           
        </Row>    
    </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note the use of `.//variableListDefault` so that it selects only descendants of the current `datasetListDefault` node. (I think doing `<xsl:for-each select="variableList/variableListDefault">` would also work in this case).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Tim. That's exactly what I was after.